# How to call CSS in a PHP "fetch" function (scriptcase / pdf form)

Tags: php, css, pdf, fetch, tcpdf

First about my environment:

1. I'm working in scriptcase v9;
2. I'm trying to create a pdf report with TCPDF library.

I'm trying to call some CSS in a PHP fetch function, but with no success:

Variant A: I tried to use a big CSS stored at the beginning of the file and I called id's from there;

```
$_style = "
    <style>

    html, body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0
    }

    table {}

    th {
        border-bottom: 0.3px solid #D2D2D2;
        height: auto;
        padding-top: 30px; 
        padding-bottom: 20px; 
        text-align: left; 
        color: #2B2B2B;
        }

    #summary_tr {padding:0px 0px;}

    #summary_tc1 {
        width: 5%;
        height: auto;   
        }
    #summary_tc2 {
        width: 5%;
        height: auto;
        border-left: 0.5px solid #D2D2D2;   
        }
    #summary_tc3 {
        width: 90%;
        height: auto;   
        }
    </style>";

    function fetch_mresumeright($resright_id)  
    {

        $server = "blabla";
        $user = "blabla";
        $pass = "blabla";
        $db = "blabla";

        $output = '';
        $con = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$db) or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($con)); 
        // Write query

        $strSQL = "SELECT 
           summary

        FROM
           _mresume
           WHERE id = ".$resright_id;

        // Execute the query.
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);

        if ($query->num_rows > 0) 
            {   

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                    {
                        $output .= '                    
                                    <tr id = "summary_tr">
                                        <td id = "summary_td_1"></td>
                                        <td id = "summary_td_2"></td>
                                        <td id = "summary_td_3">'.$row["summary"].'</td>
                                    </tr>';
                    }
                return $output;
            }
        //Close the connection
        mysqli_close($con);
    }

    $_mresumeright = fetch_mresumeright($var_id);


    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    // set default header data
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 007', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

    // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }

    $right_column = <<<EOF
    //=======right=========
    //===css
    $_style

    //===html 
    <table>
    $_mresumeright
    </table>
    EOF;
    // write the second column - for A3
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(206, '', '82', '', $right_column, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

    // reset pointer to the last page
    $pdf->lastPage();
```

Variant B: I declared each ID as a parameter and I called it in my fetch function.

```
$summary_tr = "
    padding:0px 0px;";

$summary_td_1 = "
    width: 5%;
    height: auto;";

$summary_td_2 = "
    width: 5%;
    border-left: 0.5px solid #D2D2D2;
    height: auto;";

$summary_td_3 = "
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;";

$_style = "
    <style>

    html, body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0
    }

    table {}

    th {
        border-bottom: 0.3px solid #D2D2D2;
        height: auto;
        padding-top: 30px; 
        padding-bottom: 20px; 
        text-align: left; 
        color: #2B2B2B;
        }

    </style>";

    function fetch_mresumeright($resright_id)  
    {

        $server = "blabla";
        $user = "blabla";
        $pass = "blabla";
        $db = "blabla";

        $output = '';
        $con = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$db) or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($con)); 
        // Write query

        $strSQL = "SELECT 
           summary

        FROM
           _mresume
           WHERE id = ".$resright_id;

        // Execute the query.
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);

        if ($query->num_rows > 0) 
            {   

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                    {
                        $output .= '                    
                                <tr style = "'.$summary_tr.'">
                                    <td style = "'.$summary_td_1.'"></td>
                                    <td style = "'.$summary_td_2.'"></td>
                                    <td style = "'.$summary_td_3.'">'.$row["summary"].'</td>
                                </tr>';
                    }
                return $output;
            }
        //Close the connection
        mysqli_close($con);
    }

    $_mresumeright = fetch_mresumeright($var_id);


    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    // set default header data
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 007', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

    // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }

    $right_column = <<<EOF
    //=======right=========
    //===css
    $_style

    //===html 
    <table>
    $_mresumeright
    </table>
    EOF;
    // write the second column - for A3
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(206, '', '82', '', $right_column, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

    // reset pointer to the last page
    $pdf->lastPage();
```

None have worked for me.

Any idea where did I got wrong?
Unfortunly my experience in programing is quite limited.

Thank you for your time and help, 
Dan

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple example below that is based on your code. It should help you to understand how to use HTML/CSS with TCPDF and how to insert content into the HTML.  One of the issues I noticed is that I don't see where the TCPDF library was required in your example, but it may have been done elsewhere. Additionally, you may have not called `$pdf->AddPage();`. The example should run inside the TCPDF examples directory.

```php
<?php

$styles = <<<EOF
    <style>
    .section {
        color: navy;
    }
    .row {
        background-color: green;
    }
    .cell-one {
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
    }
    </style>
EOF;

function fetchContent() {
    $row = '<tr class="row">
            <td class="cell-one">Cell One</td>
            <td>Cell Two</td>
                  </tr>';
        return str_repeat($row,20);
}

require_once('../tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$tableRows = fetchContent();
$html = <<<EOF
  $styles
  <div class="section">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>
  <table>
  $tableRows
  </table>
EOF;

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->Output('example', 'I');
```